# Babel in ConTeXt(LuaTeX)

Tags: luatex, context, babel

I am interesting in ConTeXt(LuaTeX) but my biggest problem is that I could not translate a simple program from LuaLaTeX, that uses babel, to a corresponding ConTeXt(LuaTeX) one. The code is the following:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[polutonikogreek,english]{babel}
\usepackage{luatex}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont[ExternalLocation]{TheanoDidot-Regular}
\renewcommand*{\greektext}{}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{greek}
ἡ ῥητορική  ἐστιν  ἀντίστροφος  τῇ διαλεκτικῇ:
ἀμφότεραι  γὰρ  περὶ 
τοιούτων  τινῶν  εἰσιν  ἃ κοινὰ  τρόπον  τινὰ  ἁπάντων 
ἐστὶ  γνωρίζειν 
  καὶ  οὐδεμιᾶς  ἐπιστήμης  ἀφωρισμένης: διὸ  καὶ 
πάντες  τρόπον  τινὰ 
  μετέχουσιν  ἀμφοῖν: πάντες  γὰρ  μέχρι τινὸς καὶ
ἐξετάζειν καὶ ὑπέχειν 
λόγον καὶ ἀπολογεῖσθαι καὶ κατηγορεῖν ἐγχειροῦσιν.

\selectlanguage{english}
Typing in Greek in \LaTeX{} is fun! 
\end{document}
```

Comment: So [this question](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45480/a-challenge-to-context-luatex-and-lualatex-users) was a cunning attempt to get it done?

Comment: I don't see why this is voted down so much. Maybe the question is unclear, maybe there was another attempt that failed to fit in this q&a style of the site, but IMO the question is good. It should be named "How can I do this in ConTeXt mkiv".

Comment: @PatrickGundlach Probably because the OP doesn't show much effort. He neither provides the ConTeXt code he wrote, nor does he describe the expected results or which output he gets. Maybe this information is explained in the greek text he provided, in that case I take it all back ;)

Comment: I agree with @Marco. The OP is assuming that every ConTeXt user understands what the LaTeX code does. I certainly do not understand why babel is used (hyphenation patterns?), what is `\greektext` and why it is redef-ed to `{}`, etc.

Comment: That's right @Aditya. I haven't found a way to hyphenate Greek (or other no Latin languages) using ConTeXt! Am I wrong? I could see only \language[] command in ConTeXt but only for a small number of languages(nl, fr, en, de). Also I guess that one could write very clear LuaLaTeX commands (maybe using a new .sty?) that could imitate many  ConTeXt commands(for example the ConTeXt command \useexternalfigure e.t.c) or vice versa . So the ConTeXt and LuaLaTeX are equivalent in complexity.( But this of course just my opinion.I could be wrong!) Disclaimer:  I am not an expert in LuaLaTeX orConTeXt.

Comment: The [second tutorial example](http://wiki.contextgarden.net/Second_Step) at the ConTeXt wiki shows how to change languages, and their list of language codes linked there includes both modern and ancient Greek. Not sure about hyphenation, but I'd follow others' recommendations and make an attempt at a minimal Greek ConTeXt document first.

Answer (score 6):

Maybe this is what you want:

```
\usemodule[simplefonts]
\setmainfont[TheanoDidot-Regular]                 
\setupbodyfont[12pt]
\mainlanguage[greek]
\starttext
ἡ ῥητορική  ἐστιν  ἀντίστροφος  τῇ διαλεκτικῇ:
ἀμφότεραι  γὰρ  περὶ 
τοιούτων  τινῶν  εἰσιν  ἃ κοινὰ  τρόπον  τινὰ  ἁπάντων 
ἐστὶ  γνωρίζειν 
  καὶ  οὐδεμιᾶς  ἐπιστήμης  ἀφωρισμένης: διὸ  καὶ 
πάντες  τρόπον  τινὰ 
  μετέχουσιν  ἀμφοῖν: πάντες  γὰρ  μέχρι τινὸς καὶ
ἐξετάζειν καὶ ὑπέχειν 
λόγον καὶ ἀπολογεῖσθαι καὶ κατηγορεῖν ἐγχειροῦσιν.
\language[en]
Typing in Greek in \ConTeXt{} is easy! 
\stoptext
```

1. The font is from http://www.thessalonica.org.ru/en/fonts-download.html .
2. Assuming a standalone (was minimals) installation, put it under `texmf-project/font`; then run `context --generate` and `mtxrun --script fonts --reload`.
3. Check the font with `mtxrun --script fonts --list theano --all`

The log says

```
fonts           > otf prepare > unsupported coverage contextpos for 'RQD ' Greek Caps after Accents Positioning-1
```

This means that there are some problems. I will send the example to the context ml.