# ConTeXt and OldStandard font

Tags: fonts, context

my first post here.
I need your help.

When I use LaTeX (pdfLaTeX), without problems or errors, I can load `\usepackage{OldStandard}`. So, I can use smallcaps. Now when I use ConTeXt (LuaTeX) and type `\definefontfamily [mainface] [serif] [OldStandard]` I can't use smallcaps anymore. I feel that ConText loads the "old" OldStandard package, the original one, the original one, ie the one that did not have smallcaps and therefore does not load the one that has small caps

How can I tell ConTeXt: use the new 'package'?

Thank you

**MWE LaTeX**

```
\documentclass[11pt, twoside, openright]{book}
 \usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
  \usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
   \usepackage{OldStandard}
    \begin{document}
     \textsc{Small Caps} Normal Text
      \end{document}
```

[image: MWE LaTeX SC Working]

MWE ConTeXt

```
\definepapersize[book][width=165mm, height=250mm]
 \setuppapersize[book]
  \definefontfamily[mainface][serif][OldStandard]
   \setupbodyfont[mainface, 10pt]
   \starttext
   {\sc Small Caps} Normal Text  
   \stoptext
```

[image: MWE ConTeXt SC not working]

Comment: It helps to provide a comparison between the expected output you have in LaTeX and the non-working output in ConTeXt (a MWE and screenshots, if possible).

Comment: Possibly related: OldStandard.otf implements smallcaps replacement as a 'required feature' with the RQD tag, whereas other fonts that do work with your MWE (for example Linux Libertine O) use a 'standard' OpenType feature for this. Maybe ConTeXt does not like that, nine years ago there was an issue with RQD (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/45508/babel-in-contextluatex) but I have no idea if that is still relevant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this solution:

```
\definepapersize[book][width=165mm, height=250mm]
\setuppapersize[book]
\definefontfamily[mainface][serif][sc={Old Standard Small}, force=yes]
\setupbodyfont[mainface,10pt]
   
   \starttext
   {\sc Small Caps} Normal Text  
   \stoptext
```

Comment: This does not work - it generates small caps but the font is Latin Modern and not Old Standard.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `script=latn`. Interestingly, this enables small caps not only for Latin, but also for Greek.

```
\definefontfeature[f:latn][default][script=latn]
\definefontfamily[mainface][serif][OldStandard][features=f:latn]
\setupbodyfont[mainface, 10pt]
\starttext 
{\sc Small Caps} Normal Text  
\stoptext
```

[image]